# What am I doing wrong with my 'Do' loop?

Tags: java, loops

A Java Newbie here,
              I tried to program a oracle machine and it worked. However, the last part of asking the users if they want to continue is not working. I will ask the users if they want to continue and if they did not reply 'Y','y','N' or 'n',they will have to rerun the test again.
So the problem that I am getting is this:

```
    What is the question that you want to ask?... agafds
    No! And Stop asking me!
    Continue asking?(Y/N)...Y
    Continue asking?(Y/N)...Y
    Continue asking?(Y/N)...Y
    Continue asking?(Y/N)...Y
    Continue asking?(Y/N)...Y
```

From this:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class firstClass {
public static void main(String args[]) {


    Scanner kbScanner=new Scanner(System.in);
    Random intRand=new Random();
    String yOn;

    do {
        int oneten;
        out.print("What is the question that you want to ask?... ");
        kbScanner.nextLine();
        oneten=intRand.nextInt(10)+1;

        switch (oneten) {
        case 1 :
            out.println("Not a chance, buster.");
            break;
        case 2 :
            out.println("Get a life man!");
            break;
        case 3 :
            out.println("Why are you even asking me this?!");
            break;
        case 4 :
            out.println("Depends on your thinking.");
            break;
        case 5 :
            out.println("What are you seeking for?");
            break;
        case 6 :
            out.println("Maybe... But don't trust me...");
            break;
        case 7 :
            out.println("Do I look like I care?");
            break;
        case 8 :
            out.println("Why would you even ask that?");
            break;
        case 9 :
            out.println("The chances are as thin as searching for a needle in a haystack.");
            break;
        case 10 :
            out.println("No! And Stop asking me!");
            break;
        }
        do{
            out.print("Continue asking?(Y/N)...");
            yOn=kbScanner.nextLine();
        }while (!yOn.equals("Y")||!yOn.equals("y")||!yOn.equals("N")||!yOn.equals("n"));
        out.println("Continuing");
    }while (yOn.equals("Y")||yOn.equals("y"));

}
}
```

So: The problem is that no matter what the user inputs there seems to be no difference.

Comment: Get rid of the inner do-while loop.

Comment: try use an infinity loop . `while(true)`

Comment: Check what value `yOn` *really* has when you input `Y`. It may have cr+lf appended.

Comment: Are you sure the scanner is returning a single string, and not a string with the carriage return at the end?

Comment: Guys, the inner do while is for when the user doesn't type a valid answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, the inner loop should be like this I guess:

```
do{
    out.print("Continue asking?(Y/N)...");
    yOn=kbScanner.nextLine();
}while (!yOn.equals("Y")&&!yOn.equals("y")&&!yOn.equals("N")&&!yOn.equals("n"));
```

Answer (score 3):

```
!yOn.equals("Y")||!yOn.equals("y")||!yOn.equals("N")||!yOn.equals("n")
```

This condition is always going to evaluate to true, if it's Y than it's not N so it's still true and vice versa.  Change your `||` to `&&`.

```
!yOn.equals("Y")&&!yOn.equals("y")&&!yOn.equals("N")&&!yOn.equals("n")
```

Comment: i think it is like `yOn.equals("Y")||yOn.equals("y")||yOn.equals("N")||yOn.equals("n")`

Comment: That is logically equivalent and probably a better solution, but either way

Comment: It is equivalent if the whole term is negated ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws of course).

Comment: Oh right, it's not actually equivalent, ignore my comment, mine is correct, also Radhamani's answer would also work

Answer (score 0):

After the switch-case, don't have another do..while loop. Retain only the outer loop:

```
//do{
        out.print("Continue asking?(Y/N)...");
        yOn=kbScanner.nextLine();
   // }while (!yOn.equals("Y")||!yOn.equals("y")||!yOn.equals("N")||!yOn.equals("n"));
  //  out.println("Continuing");
//Retain the outer do..while condition
}while (yOn.equals("Y")||yOn.equals("y"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this replace the first while loop by

```
while (!(yOn.equals("Y")||yOn.equals("y")||yOn.equals("N")||yOn.equals("n")));
```

Answer (score 0):

So some tips to you

1 - Use `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `equals("Y")||!yOn.equals("y")` 
2 - remove the middle `while` you logic should be like follow

```
main {    
   read option

    do {
      process 
      read option 
    } while (continue ?) // validate here 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I found it useful.

Answer (score 0):

Try to replace

```
do{
            out.print("Continue asking?(Y/N)...");
            yOn=kbScanner.nextLine();
        }while (!yOn.equals("Y")&&!yOn.equals("y")&&!yOn.equals("N")&&!yOn.equals("n"));
       out.println("Continuing");
```

By

```
out.print("Continue asking?(Y/N)...");
yOn=kbScanner.nextLine();
```

You really do not need the inner do-while loop as the outer loop can do the same thing for you.

Try [this](http://www.javawithus.com/tutorial/nested-loops) or [this](http://mathbits.com/MathBits/Java/Looping/NestedFor.htm) to see when the nested loops are really useful.

Comment: Yes, thats true but I need the correct user input. For example, if the user types in "x" instead of y or n, the program will automatically exit. Or maybe, I am not seeing your point clearly.